# failed to download When creating a new project in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, sdk, new-project

`Hello World`

I want to create a new Flutter project, but it gives me this error
[image]

My internet connection is fine.
When I put this link in the browser, I can download it directly.
But it gives this error when creating the project.
Is it possible that the flutter has cached somewhere?
I tried with Android Studio and it gave the same error again.
How can I fix it?

I checked the internet connection several times
I even used other people's internet, but it didn't open.
I updated the filter but it didn't work
I also used the flutter clean command, but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You get "exception: 403"
It means you must use VPN to get success. If you use a VPN that didn't work, change it and buy a powerful one.

Comment: i use a puwerful vpn ,
i use a dns
i can download tree of things , but the lase one give me this error

Comment: @hosseindarvishi if you have v2ray configs, connect with nekoray app on vpn mode, it would solve your problem, otherwise your vpn has dns leaking. This url give you a list of your vpn DNS. They must be the same location as your vpn ip. For example, location of your vpn ip is Germany, then all of DNS lists location must be on Germany, the url is: dnsleaktest.com